# Limit as $x$ to zero, $(x(\sin x)^8)/(x^3-\sin(x^3))$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

limit as $x\to 0$ of $\frac{(x(\sin x)^8)}{x^3-\sin(x^3)}$

I can't find solve of this problem. Please help.

Comment: It will help Readers to respond if you provide context for you Question.  What examples or theorems have you studied that relate to this problem?  What approaches did they suggest to you and what difficulty did you find in trying them?  What makes this problem interesting to you?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that might help is to note that

$$(\sin x)^8 =\left (\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^8x^8.$$

Since that fraction $\to 1,$ we can look at

$$\frac{x^9}{x^3-\sin(x^3)}$$

instead. We can now, if we like, let $y=x^3$ to get

$$\frac{y^3}{y-\sin(y)}.$$

We want the limit of this as $y\to 0.$ Now recall $\sin y = y-y^3/3!+O(y^5)$ to finish up.

Comment: Thanks you too, I'm new in here, but i'm very like this.

Answer (score 0):

Use Taylor series to find that $$\dfrac{(x(\sin x)^8)}{x^3-\sin(x^3)}= \dfrac{x^9+o(x^9)}{\dfrac{x^9}{6}+o(x^9)} \to 6$$